# Images will not upload on web server but ok on local

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some images on server i want to upload it on another server i make code to upload all images on server but it is OK to upload on local but i didn't know what is wrong in that it can't be upload on server

```
      try
        {
            byte[] content;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                content = br.ReadBytes(500000);
                br.Close();
            }
            response.Close();

            string CompleteDPath = "ftp path";
            string UName = "abc";
            string PWD = "123";



            WebRequest reqObj = WebRequest.Create(CompleteDPath + file_name);
            reqObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            reqObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UName, PWD);
            reqObj.GetRequestStream().Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            reqObj = null;



            //FileStream fs = new FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Create);
            //BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

            //bw.Write(content);
            //fs.Close();
            //bw.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any exception error ?

Comment: No there is no exception error...

Comment: check write permission on the server

Answer (score 0):

have a try;

```
byte[] content;       

HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);    

WebResponse response1 = request1.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response1.GetResponseStream();

using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    content = br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    br.Close();
}
response1.Close();


FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp_path");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc", "123");
request.ContentLength = content.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

Comment: i get "This stream does not support seek operations" exception with this code

Comment: in which line you get the exception?

Comment: this one content = br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);